# showing popup with cocos2d v3

Tags: iphone, ios7, cocos2d-iphone

I need to know what is the best way to implement a popup with cocos2d v3.
I currently create a CCNode class for my popups that has as its background a sprite 200x300 with various CCButtons and images, though I'm not sure it is the correct way.

I explain how I've implement it : on my GameScene (the main scene), when the game ends, I want to show a popup to ask the user if he wants to use other lives or end the game, so I add as a child my CCNode class ContinuePopup:

```
[self addChild:[ContinuePopup node] z:50];
```

I see it correctly, and on this popup I can choose yes or no... 
if I choose NO I wish to show the game over popup (another CCNode class) so inside my ContinuePopup.m :

```
GameScene *gm = [[GameScene alloc]init]; 
[gm viewGameOver];
[self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
```

it calls the method viewGameOver on the GameScene :

```
- (void)viewGameOver { 
[self addChild:[GameOverPopup node] z:400]; }
```

my problem is that I don't see the GameOverPopup! it doesn't appear!
it disappears correctly the ContinuePopup but GameOverPopup doesn't appear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps simply not presenting the new scene?

```
GameScene *gm = [[GameScene alloc]init]; 
[gm viewGameOver];

// Try this:
[self.view presentScene:gm];
```

Comment: my scene is already presented, it is under the popup! it enter in the method viewGameOver (I see with breakpoint) but it doesn't show GameOverPopup... I don't have to show another scene, I have to show another popup (CCNode class) ...my problem is that if I show them individually working properly and appear but one behind the other, the second does not appear

Comment: Given the code fragments you posted, what you do is that you create a new instance of GameScene, you then add the GameOverPopup instance to this new GameScene instance, and then you don't present the GameScene. Verify that you really intended to add the GameOverPopup to a new instance of GameScene rather than the existing and currently presented scene.

Comment: No, I want to add the GameOverPopup to the existing instance of GameScene but I don't know what is the correct way because I have to call the viewGameOver method from ContinuePopup class

Comment: Within the ContinuePopup instance you can access the scene instance via self.scene so this should work: [self.scene addChild:[GameOverPopup node] z:400];

Comment: ah ok! I didn't know I could do this, so I can also remove ContinuePopup child from the same class...ok perfect...thanks a lot!

Comment: but if I want to call a GameScene method within the CCNode class ContinuePopup without creating a new instance of GameScene, what is the correct way?

Comment: Assuming that a GameScene instance is the currently presented scene, this works from any node after it has been added as child (so not within the init/node methods): GameScene* gameScene = (GameScene*)self.scene;